# How to set content-type in node-fetch

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

this is my code:

```js
return fetch("https://www.motiondevelopment.top/api/v1.2/bots/" + botid + "/stats", {
        method: "post",
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "key": apikey,
        },
        body: { "guilds": serverNumber }
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json().then((data) => {
            return data;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("[MotionBotList]: " + err);
        })
    });
```

At the moment it will not use the content-type application/json and I don't know why. Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `stringify` **body object**.

here is the updated code:

```js
fetch("https://www.motiondevelopment.top/api/v1.2/bots/" + botid + "/stats", {
  method: "post",
  headers: { 
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "key": apikey,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ "guilds": serverNumber })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

you can read details about **feach api** [here](https://foyez.netlify.app/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api/)